# Classes with different files and passing vars between functions 

Tags: python

How can i pass many variables to a function in a different file?

I noticed that some files only have functions (they are grouped in individual files). For example, one file to control install (that has function for new installs, update installs, etc...) , other to grant access (create new user, delete user, update user).And those functions receive a quite amount of vars , as an example:

```
access_tool.add_user(cur,con,env,family,iserver,version,login,
                           password,prefix,proxyUser,proxyPass,
                           proxyServer,user,pass)
```

So, the access_tool( the file ) and the function ( get_add_info ) receives those vars from another file, and those vars are dynamic (results  from  database query). How can I pass those values to a function in a different file elegantly?

**Example:**

We have 2 important files:

1. a.properties - Which contains database info and credentials
2. mainfile.py - Main file, called to execute functions for example:

   - add-user ENV newuser newuserpass

The add-user calls a function from the file access_tool.py called add_user.

What mainfile.py does is (for this example of user creation ) depending on the environment sent through the input, it will do a query into the database to select the X servers to add the user and it will store the result into the vars ( to be used into a array loop ):

```
cur,con,env,family,iserver,version,login,password,prefix,proxyUser,proxyPass,proxyServer
```

So, those vars will receive from loop, 5 , 10 or more servers to add. The only variables that is static is newuser, and newuserpass (wich receives from the input )

The only problem I have is to make a decision about how I can pass (or share ) the variables to a function on another file.

Some people from work suggest that i keep all of then at the same file, and instead of having many files for each class, just have one file with all the classes.

Comment: Your english is way above SO-average :)

Comment: @Thales, above the average of a StackOverflow user.

Comment: Edited, to fix grammar and formating :)

Comment: but what is the problem with the current solution? what are you trying to fix, and why?

Comment: The way the code is written... not easy to read and does not follows PEP8. And since i have to organize that, i will try to do how it was supose to be.

Comment: Please... if someone edit my post to correct grammar.. correct then correctly :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of **files** in Python is vague. The phrase 'variable from a file` doesn't mean anything. You must be aware of how these vars are instantiated and what is their scope.

Values in Python do not live in files, they live in memory, and are pointed to by variables.

For functions that take a lot of parameters, it is common to use named arguments:

```
def fun(**args):
  param1 = args.get('param1', 'default_value')
  param2 = ... # etc

fun(param1='val1', param2 = 'val2')
```

Which might be the elegance you are looking for :)

So your code may look like this:

```
def main():
  #initialization 
  import access_tool
  con = database_connection()
  servers = query_database_for_servers()

  for server in servers:
    #assume server is a dict of values
    access_tool.add_user ( **server )
```

And your `add_user` function may be modified like this:

```
def add_user ( **params ):
   # connect to params['server'] using params['env']
   # and add user with other params[]
```

Comment: Updating the question with more info regarding it

Answer (score 0):

That depends how the values are stored. If e.g. they are read from a configuration file and you store the configuration values as a dictionary, you can use dictionary unpacking to pass the values into your method invocation. E.g. `access_tool.add_user(**settings)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass variable between many functions, I suggest you take a look at passing objects.
[See my answer here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642948/492620).
And you should definitely look at the module [ConfigParser,](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html?highlight=configparser#ConfigParser) in case you want to do more complicated stuff.